# The process cannot access the file - after disposing InputStream

Tags: c#, asp.net

I perform some image uploads on my server. The image save operation looks like:

```
 var image = Request.Files[0];
 image.SaveAs(gFilePath);
 image.InputStream.Flush();
 image.InputStream.Close();
 image.InputStream.Dispose();
```

but, even after disposing the `InputStream` sometimes I get the error `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` The only process which has the acces to that image is the project instance. So, what's going on ?

Comment: Try using `using` and place the code within. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/yh598w02(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Which line is generating the error?

Comment: The exception could thrown be due to another thread in the web service in mid-save of an image to the same path (global `gFilePath`).  But assuming there's only one thread for now, it's possible that the disk write is incomplete when image.SaveAs (even Dispose, or a using clause) returns.  This could be due to file system latency, which is more likely to affect your process if it processes files in rapid succession.  With this problem I never had any success delaying the process (e.g. on exception wait 10 msec and try again).  Try saving each file to a distinct name.

Answer (score 0):

In your code it is not ensured that the stream is closed properly. If an error is occurred before calling Close or Dispose, the resource remains blocked. Use try-catch-finally and release resources in the finally block, log failures in the catch block - do not use Close and Dispose too, Dispose is enough.

Answer (score 0):

`Request.Files.*` is not a stream to the file on the disk of the client. The server does not have access to the disk of the client. That would be a major security issue.

This stream represents what the server received on the network. The error message you posted cannot come from this stream. You have misinterpreted the exception. It came from somewhere else. Maybe it came from the `SaveAs` call. In that case it would mean that the target path is in use.

The question does not have enough information to tell from where the exception came because you posted only minimal details. Make it a habit to read and understand all exception information.